# Twilio cURL calling a phone

Tags: php, curl, twilio, phone-call

Based on the documentation of Twilio and Curl I have a php curl routine:

```
function twilio($mobile,$msg,$twoCode){
$url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID.'/Calls.json';
$CallURL = 'http://Myweb.com/code/say/'.$twoCode;
$auth = TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID.":".TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
$fields = array(
 'To' =>  $mobile  ,
 'From' => '+16262471234'  , // My Number
 'Url' => urlencode( $CallURL ) ,
 'Method'=>'GET' ,
 'FallbackMethod'=>'GET',
 'StatusCallbackMethod'=>'GET',
 'Record'=>'false'
);
$post = http_build_query($fields);
$curl = curl_init($url);
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 'Mozilla 5.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 7' ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

It gives me an error:

```
{"code": 21213, "message": "No 'From' number is specified", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21213", "status": 400}
```

I tried all the options, can anyone help?

I edited and added a "+" for the "From" number. But still the error remains the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems there isn't the country code `+NN` or `0NN` in from number

Comment: I edited and added "+" for the "From" number, the error still remains the same,

Comment: Have you adden  your country code?

Comment: Yes I added "+1" to My Phone number of Twilio

Answer (score 4):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Your code is really close. Just two small changes should resolve your issue. First you need to remove this line: 
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 7' ));`

This was truncating your [POST data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) which resulted in the "From" information not being sent.

Second, you don't need to urlencode the $CallURL because curl handles this for us.

Once you make both of these changes your code should look like this and run without an error:

```
function twilio($mobile,$msg,$twoCode){
  $url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'. TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID.'/Calls.json';
  $CallURL = 'http://Myweb.com/code/say/'.$twoCode;
  $auth = TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID .":". TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
  $fields = array(
   'To' =>  $mobile  , 
   'From' => '+16262471234'  , // My Number
   'Url' => $CallURL,
   'Method'=>'GET' ,
   'FallbackMethod'=>'GET',
   'StatusCallbackMethod'=>'GET',
   'Record'=>'false'
  );
  $post = http_build_query($fields);
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 'Mozilla 5.0');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);

  $resp = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);
}
```

Let me know if this gets your issues resolved.

Comment: Can I ask a really stupid question. Does this end up with a call between two telephone number or do you have to configure Twilio with the "my" phone (as in a real one I can pick up in my hand). I am only doing texts at the moment but have always been very confused about real phone calls via Twilio. Seems there are 3 numbers involved; 1. twilioNumber - the number I bought from Twilio, 2. destination number and 3. myNumber - a phone I can speak with... or I suppose 4 talk via my PC. Sorry this all does my head in a bit. I am much better with punched cards and paper tape! TIA Steve